# External monitor slow/laggy when in standlone mode

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu, external-monitor

Recently, I installed an external GPU (HD6870) on my laptop which connects to an external monitor. Every time that I extend desktops, the graphics work just fine. The problem arises when I try to disable the built-in display of my laptop. The screen becomes laggy and, when watching a video, the quality is awful with motion.

I only have this issue with ubuntu (Windows works flawlessly). I tried installing the fglrx drivers but they are not supported on 16.04. The open-source radeon drivers come pre-installed in ubuntu.

Here are the contents of [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23963514) after I **enable** the built-in display:

```
[  2159.566] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3046x1050
[  2159.574] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1366x768@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (1680, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[  2160.064] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.175] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.271] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.375] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.487] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.591] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
[  2160.692] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
```

Here are the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` after I **disable** the built-in display:

```
[  2249.382] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 1680x1050
[  2250.252] (--) RADEON(G0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 225000KHz
```

Comment: Here it is: https://paste.ubuntu.com/23963514

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem (Ubuntu 18) and could **solve it** by selected the **'proprietary, tested'** driver for my graphic card!
In other words, the recommended one.

You should **check if you are using the 'official' graphic driver** or another one / old one like this:

- Open the "Software & Update" app
- Click on the "Additional Drivers" tab and wait a bit for it to load
- Make sure to select the driver with the "**(proprietary, tested)**" text!
- Click on the "Apply changes"
- Restart computer

In my case, I was using the "*X.Org X Server - Nouveau*" driver (I can't remember how/when I selected this one..)

I switched to "*NVIDIA driver 440 **(proprietary, tested)***" an rebooted my PC: no more issue / lags when using external screen only!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution is make prime-select use nvidia not on-damand.
Run `sudo prime-select nvidia` to do this.

Comment: Well, thanks, it is a bit smoother and also the text is not so blurry

Comment: But it consumes more power, because dGPU keeps working.

Comment: After switching to nvidia AND restarting, no more blurriness for me. Also transitions are not slow. Of course it uses more power but I have it connected to the electricity network while on my desktop. If I happen to move I will switch to Intel